# Power BI - Show Sum of column in table but show average for each line

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, summarize

I have data for orders which have a row for each line item in the order, and I would like to summarise the data for each order by grouping the total of each order (by order number) and I then have another page to drill down into the line items of a particular order. At the moment I have set up an SQL view that has entries for each line item of the orders with a column for the total of the whole order (this number is repeated over all the entries for a particular order number). Below is an examples of the SQL view I am depicting:

| Order_Number | Line_Item_Number | Total_for_Order |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | $2000 |
| 1 | 2 | $2000 |
| 1 | 3 | $2000 |
| 2 | 1 | $1000 |
| 2 | 2 | $1000 |

What I would like to have in Power BI is to show the data in a table showing only one line per order number but summarising the column for the totals with the sum of the column. At the moment I am having trouble because in order to summarise the data in the table I could use either max, average, or min, on the Total_for_Order column, but then the "Total" at the bottom of the Power BI table becomes a max, average, or min of the column. Basically I would like to see a table as below:

| Order_Number | Total_for_Order |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | $2000 |
| 2 | $1000 |
| Total | $3000 |

What is the best way to achieve this? Is it better to create a new SQL view, or is there a way to sum the column of the Power BI table even though I would like to show an average for the Total_for_Order rows?

Thanks, and I hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting table:

[image]

Create a measure:

```
Measure = 

VAR t = SUMMARIZE('Table', 'Table'[Order_Number], "@max", CALCULATE(MAX('Table'[Total_for_Order])))
RETURN 
SUMX(t, [@max])
```

Create a visual:

[image]